# Testing a fresh ROS installation on Slackware 14.2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After a joyful 4 day long session of coffee and swearing in different unparseable languages I can finally say: ROS and Gazebo are compiling from source and working on Slackware 14.2. Now the question:

How can I test a fresh installation of ROS? I'm a little new to it, so I just started roscore, got a beautiful "started core service [/rosout]" and ... what now? I'm browsing through wiki and can't really find a topic entitled "How to check if everything in your ROS is working in 500 easy steps", can anyone help a little or just point me in a general direction? Because I'm pretty sure after what I had to do to the source files to make them compile there should be a plentiful of bugs hidden in there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243884/testing-a-fresh-ros-installation-on-slackware-14.2/) by [anilinverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/27994/anilinverse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most packages have unit tests; particularly the core ROS packages. These will cover the basics like publish/subscribe, services, message generation, actionlib, and most of the other things that are testable in a command-line environment.

If you built with catkin_make, running tests is just `catkin_make run_tests`

If you built with catkin_make_isolated, things may be a bit more complicated; I haven't tried it but I think you can run catkin tests in catkin_make_isolated with `catkin_make_isolated --catkin-make-args run_tests`

Both commands will output the test status as they build, but you probably don't want to sift through all of that. Both runs should produce junit-style test result files; for catkin_make they'll be in the build folder; for catkin_make_isolated they may be scattered around the workspace.

In either case, catkin provides a small command-line tool that will walk the directory tree, gather test result files and summarize them: `catkin_test_results`

In addition to running the tests, I'd suggest that you run rviz and rqt manually to verify that they work; the GUI tools are rather difficult to test in an automated fashion.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0